# Hall $\pi$-subgroup and $HN=G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $\pi$ be any set of prime numbers. A finite group $H$ is a $\pi$-group if all primes that divide $|H|$ lie in $\pi$. If $|G|<\infty$, then a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$ is a $\pi$-subgroup $H$ such that $|G:H|$ is divisible by no prime in $\pi$. Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism defined on $G$.
>
> If $H\subseteq G$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup, show that $\phi(G)$ is a $\pi$-group iff $HN=G$, where $N=\text{ker}(\phi)$.

If $HN=G$, then $\phi(H)=\phi(G)$ since $\phi(N)=1$, and since $\phi(H)$ divides $H$, which is a $\pi$-subgroup, we must have that $\phi(G)$ is a $\pi$-group.

But what about the other direction? Assume that $\phi(G)$ is a $\pi$-group. This means all primes dividing $|\phi(G)|$ are in $\pi$, all primes dividing $|H|$ are in $\pi$, and $|G:H|$ is divisible by no prime in $\pi$. We have $|G| = |H||G:H|$, and $|\phi(G)|$ divides $|G|$. How can we prove that $HN=G$ from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N\subset HN$, hence $[G:HN]=[\phi(G):\phi(HN)]$. But $[G:HN]$ is "$\pi$-free", hence $[\phi(G):\phi(HN)]$ is "$\pi$-free". But $\phi(G)$ is a $\pi$-group...

Comment: Ah, do you mean $\pi$-free instead of $\phi$-free?

Comment: I think I get it now... quite an elegant way to prove $G=HN$, by proving $[G:HN]=[\phi(G):\phi(HN)]=1$!

Comment: @Paul S.: Of course, thank you! I corrected the answer.

Comment: You are welcom!

Comment: @BorisNovikov what does $ "\pi-free "$ mean?